how to properly create files permission on Google drive Rest API using curl php
Am trying to create google drive permission on a file via Curl in PHP but The Google Drive Create Permission API seems to throws Errors.
google drive API
Here is Create File Permission API Sample Request Data
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FILE_ID/permissions

{
  "requests": [
    {
        "type": "user",
        "role": "commenter",
        "emailAddress": "nancyxxxx@gmail.com"
    }
  ]
}

I have tried 2 sample Code below
Below is my sample code 1.
   $access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
  $file_id ='file id goes here';


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/$file_id/permissions");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    "Authorization: Bearer $access_token",
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
]);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n  \"requests\": [\n    {\n        \"type\": \"anyone\",\n        \"role\": \"reader\"\n\n    }\n  ]\n}");
  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{\n  "requests": [\n    {\n        "type": "anyone",\n        "role": "reader"\n\n    }\n  ]\n}');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\n  \"requests\": [\n    {\n        \"type\": \"anyone\",\n        \"role\": \"reader\"\n\n    }\n  ]\n}");


$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);

Below is my sample code 2.
       $access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
      $file_id ='file id goes here';
$headers = array(
"Authorization: Bearer $access_token",
"Content-Type: application/json"
);

$post_fields = '{
  "requests": [
    {
        "type": "anyone",
        "role": "reader"
    }
  ]
}';

 

$ch = curl_init();                                                       
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/$file_id/permissions");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
$response = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($response);

Here is the error both 2 code above throws
{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "The permission type field is required.", "errors": [ { "message": "The permission type field is required.", "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "location": "permission.type", "locationType": "other" } ] } } string(323) "{ "error": { "code": 400, "message": "The permission type field is required.", "errors": [ { "message": "The permission type field is required.", "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "location": "permission.type", "locationType": "other" } ] } } " 

it seems this permmission request data  below is not properly passed in the API or that Googgle Drive Rest API has some bugs. Can someone help me out.
{
      "requests": [
        {
            "type": "anyone",
            "role": "reader"
    
        }
      ]
    }


Can't tell exactly from the documentation, but I'm guessing this is supposed to be sent as Content-Type: application/json - whereas PHP cURL, when it gets a string value passed for CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, likely sends application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Try and add the Content-Type header yourself.

@CBroe Thanks for getting back to me.
I have tried all the Content-Type but the error still persist.

In your script, please modify your request body in your "Below is my sample code 2." as follows and test it again.
From:
$post_fields = '{
  "requests": [
    {
        "type": "anyone",
        "role": "reader"
    }
  ]
}';

To:
$post_fields = '{"type": "anyone", "role": "reader"}';

Reference:

Method: permissions.create


please i need your help too on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78640823/how-to-properly-get-lst-of-all-files-in-a-folder-in-google-drive-using-curl-php   thanks

@Nancy Moore Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, when I saw it, I confirmed that your issue has already been resolved. I think that the reason for File not found is due to that you used the filename as the folder ID.

Thanks for your response. its working now..

Please can you help me on Google drive file upload at this question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78644862/how-to-properly-upload-file-to-google-drive-via-curl-php    Thanks

@Nancy Moore About your new question Please can you help me on Google drive file upload at this question. stackoverflow.com/questions/78644862/… Thanks, I think that my this answer might be an answer to your new question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60823403
