how to properly get lst of all files in a folder in google drive using Curl php
Am following this google drive Search API Google Drive API
I used the code below to successfully display all files and folder in google drive and is working fine.
$access_token = 'xxxxxxxx';
$headers = array(
"Authorization: Bearer $access_token",
"Content-Type: application/json"
);



$ch = curl_init();                                                       
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?trashed=false");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
$response = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($response);

Here is my issue
I need to get all files in a specific folder eg myvideo_folder
I have tried Code below but cannot get it to work. it throw error
{ "error": { "code": 404, "message": "File not found: .", "errors": [ { "message": "File not found: .", "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound", "location": "fileId", "locationType": "parameter" } ] } } " 

Here is the code
$access_token = 'xxxxx';
$headers = array(
"Authorization: Bearer $access_token",
"Content-Type: application/json"
);

$folder_name='myvideo_folder';
$ch = curl_init();                                                       
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='$folder_name' in parents");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%27$folder_name%27%20in%20parents");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
$response = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($response);


Have you tried not to encode your query?

This is how I encoded my query that shows the error  stated in the post.  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%27$folder_name%27%20in%20parents");

if tried not to encode the query as per  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='$folder_name' in parents");  it will show bool(false)

You first need to get the drive folder id (query with "name='foldername' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false"),  then again requery with the "folderid in parent" to get the files. It is better to use google drive api client for php https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

@shirshak007 you can update your response as the right answer between Thanks

First need to get the google drive folder id. For that, query with
$query1 = "name='".$foldername."' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and trashed=false";

Then again requery with
$query2 = "$folderid in parents";

This way you can get the files.
Although, it is better and simple to use

Google drive api client for PHP : github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client

