How to properly upload file to Google Drive via curl PHP
I am trying to upload files to Google Drive via curl in PHP leveraging this API sample: Google Drive File Upload API.
Here is my issue:
When I run the code below. I got a successful message as per below but no file is uploaded to that folder.
Here is the Google API Response
string(121) "{ "kind": "drive#file", "id": "171bgh8-nDojxGjd_Fxxxxxxx", "name": "Untitled", "mimeType": "image/png" } " 

Here is the code
$file_path = 'baby.png';
$folder_id = 'id of the folder goes here'; // ID of the folder you want to upload to

$mimetype=  mime_content_type($file_path);
$filename=  basename($file_path);


$headers = array(
"Authorization: Bearer $access_token",
"Content-Type: $mimetype"
);


$post_fields = json_encode(array(
'name' => basename($file_path),
'parents' => array($folder_id),
'metadata' => "{name :$filename};type=application/json;charset=UTF-8",
 'file' => new CURLFile($file_path, $mimetype),
));

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);

How do I get the file uploaded to that folder via folder ID?

I am not sure what is the reason from re-inventing the wheal.
Google already provides an SDK for that purpose
first install it using composer
composer require google/apiclient

After that you could try something like that
use Google\Client;
use Google\Service\Drive;
# TODO - PHP client currently chokes on fetching start page token
function uploadBasic()
{
    try {
        $client = new Client();
        $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
        $client->addScope(Drive::DRIVE);
        $driveService = new Drive($client);
        $fileMetadata = new Drive\DriveFile(array(
        'name' => 'photo.jpg'));
        $content = file_get_contents('../files/photo.jpg');
        $file = $driveService->files->create($fileMetadata, array(
            'data' => $content,
            'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
            'uploadType' => 'multipart',
            'fields' => 'id'));
        printf("File ID: %s\n", $file->id);
        return $file->id;
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "Error Message: ".$e;
    } 

}

You could check the docs here

Thanks @Joseph but  I want to use Curl

if so even try to use HTTP client to help you on that than curl like using guzzle client

@NancyMoore but why do you want to use curl for this? The SDK takes away all the pain and hassle of building the request yourself in the exact right way. Why re-invent the wheel?
